# Append element into a numpy empty array, but he maximum index will be fixed as 2

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append, stack

I want to append some element to a fixed size empty array. But when I append more than 2 elements, the error came out, as:

```
[1 2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ctchan127au/Desktop/DSA/WS3/tryNP.py", line 8, in <module>
    stack = np.append(stack[2], 3)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np

stack = np.empty(5, dtype=object)

stack = np.append(stack[0], 1)
stack = np.append(stack[1], 2)
print(stack)
stack = np.append(stack[2], 3)
print(stack)
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`np.empty` with `object` makes an array full of `None`:

```
In [12]: stack = np.empty(5, dtype=object)
In [13]: stack
Out[13]: array([None, None, None, None, None], dtype=object)
```

`np.append` makes a new array, here joining a `None` and `1`:

```
In [14]: np.append(stack[0],1)
Out[14]: array([None, 1], dtype=object)
```

Do you really want to assign that to `stack`, loosing the original 5 element array?

Using `Out[14]` instead of that `stack` assignment, see what the next `append` does:

```
In [15]: np.append(Out[14][1],2)
Out[15]: array([1, 2])
```

And the error line should now be clear.  You are trying to `append` to a non-existent 3rd element of a 2 element array:

```
In [16]: np.append(Out[15][2],3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [16] in <cell line: 1>
    np.append(Out[15][2],3)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

`np.empty` and `np.append` are NOT list clones.  Pay close attention to what each step does.  Reading the docs is also a good idea, especially if behavior doesn't match your guesses.

I suspect you were trying to replicate this:

```
In [17]: alist=[]
In [18]: alist.append(1)
In [19]: alist.append(2)
In [20]: alist.append(3)
In [21]: alist
Out[21]: [1, 2, 3]
```

Or are you trying to assign values, one at a time, to an array:

```
In [39]: stack = np.zeros(5, dtype=int)
In [40]: stack[0] = 1
In [41]: stack[1] = 2
In [42]: stack[2] = 3
In [43]: stack
Out[43]: array([1, 2, 3, 0, 0])
```

while lists are designed for growth, especially with end `append`, "growing/shrinking" numpy arrays is generally not a good idea.  You have to make a new array with each change (I'm glossing over the rarely use `resize` method).

Comment: Since my assignment told me to set the data type as object. However, my tutor suggest to use the numpy array. But is the alist=[] data type can set as object? or it is already an object array? no differences?

Comment: This does not look like a good numpy assignment.  A beginner should not be use object dtype, nor trying to build arrays iteratively.  Maybe I should have first asked what result are they expecting.   Repeated `np.append` is possible, but experienced users strongly discourage it.